# SQLite Database runs very slow with very simple query. How can I improve performance?

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, cloud

For a research project I have created a sqlite database that stores news articles. Currently the database is 272GB big and stored on a cloud volume of 2TB. My cloud machine has 32 Core and 128GB of RAM and is attached to this volume.

I am running the following query:
`"select * from articles where year={} and source in {}"`
in which I replace '{}' with a year and about 6 sources.

Running this query takes about 1h and results in about 450k rows being yielded by the DB (out of 90 million total rows). While doing this, CPU usage is virtually at 0%.

The table has been created this way:
`"create table if not exists articles(source_id TEXT, source TEXT, day INTEGER, month INTEGER, year INTEGER, program_name TEXT, transcript TEXT, parliament INTEGER, top1_topic INTEGER, top1_acc REAL, top2_topic INTEGER, top2_acc REAL, top3_topic INTEGER, top3_acc REAL, emotionality_nrc REAL, emotionality_liwc REAL, subject_codes TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (source_id, day, month, year, program_name));"`
and I have indexed source and year separately.

The query explanation is:
`` QUERY PLAN`--SEARCH articles USING INDEX idx_articles_on_year_source (year=? AND source=?) ``

I ran an ioping test at the directory the database is stored and got:

```
--- . (ext4 /dev/vdb) ioping statistics ---
99 requests completed in 31.1 ms, 396 KiB read, 3.18 k iops, 12.4 MiB/s
generated 100 requests in 1.65 min, 400 KiB, 1 iops, 4.04 KiB/s
min/avg/max/mdev = 157.4 us / 314.5 us / 477.6 us / 76.8 us
```

and the following fio test `fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=fiotest --filename=testfio --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=8G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75` gave this result:

```
read: IOPS=10.8k, BW=42.3MiB/s (44.4MB/s)
write: IOPS=3619, BW=14.1MiB/s (14.8MB/s)
```

I also tried things like ```PRAGMA synchronous=OFF`` and different journals such as memory and WAL.

I am a bit lost on why the database is so slow and what I should do to improve the speed. Have I done a stupid mistake in the setup or is the infrastructure just not good? Should I switch to a data warehouse solution such as amazon redshift?

PS: I am connecting to the db via pythons sqlite3 library and use the following code

```
 def select_articles_by_year_and_sources(self, year, sources=None):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        rows = cur.execute(select_articles_by_year_and_sources_query.format(year, sources))

        return iter(ResultIterator(rows))

conn = db.NewsDb(path_db) # connect to database
articles = list(conn.select_articles_by_year_and_sources(year, sources))
conn.close()
```

I just tried copying a 8GB file from the attach volume to my VM. It took 2m and 30sec with the bash cp command. I guess that means the bandwidth to the attached volume is quite slow?

Comment: (Also, bind values to parameters in your query instead of inserting them directly in a query string; https://bobby-tables.com/python for details)

Comment: SQLite is clearly not designed for such a huge database. It is meanly designed for small embedded DB (that could fit in RAM). Please use a better suited DB system. Beside this, your storage device is a slow HDD (operating at ~50 MiB/s with <100 IOPS) which tends to make DB accesses very slow. Consider using a SSD if possible. It should be 5x-200x faster (mainly because of a x100-x1000 IOPS). Indexing is critical to improve performance but SQLite is not great for that.

Comment: The ioping looks pretty good (suspiciously so for network attached storage) while the bandwidth is crap. At this scale, on a cloud service no less, can't you switch to a proper database service?

Answer (score 2):

Your query plan shows that the index on the two columns in your `WHERE` clause - `year` and `source` - is being used, so you might not be able to speed it up. It's possible, though, that depending on the distribution of your data, instead of having an index on `articles(year, source)`, one on `articles(source, year)` might be better by pruning out more rows faster.

You can try adding that new index, and then running an [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on the database to generate statistics about the indexes that SQLite uses to pick which of several possible indexes it thinks will work better. Check the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output after to see if it's using the new index or still on the old one, and then drop whichever index isn't being used (Or if it's slower in practice with the new index, drop that one).

Another option is using the [sqlite3 command line program's `.expert` command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_), which generates index suggestions for queries, to see what it comes up with in this case.

Comment: Increasing the page [cache size](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) if you're running repeated queries on this database in the same connection might help too.

Comment: I tried the new index but unfortunately there is only a slight improvement in query speed, but it took ages to calculate it. Will try bigger cache size now.